# Windows battery meter utility suggestions

Tags: windows, display, taskbar, battery

Can you suggest a good **battery meter** utility for Windows? Battery status being graphically displayed in the taskbar is the (obvious) minimum requirement. Anything else the utility can inform or do is a plus.

(If the battery meter taskbar icon is turned off by an admin it does not appear for non-admin users. That could be another reason to look for a battery meter utility apart from the one which comes with Windows.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BatteryBar](http://www.osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/index.html) works on XP, Vista and Windows 7.  This is the one I eventually ended up using and would recommend.  Article on it from LifeHacker [here](http://lifehacker.com/5145063/batterybar-adds-a-power-meter-to-the-taskbar), see image below:

[image]

If you want to use something neat for just Vista/Windows 7, [BattCursor](http://en.battcursor.net/details.aspx) is my other recommendation.  It has the added ability of disabling the Aero theme at a certain battery level to help squeeze a few extra minutes' juice out of the battery.  It can even change the colour of the taskbar or mouse cursor.  [image]

[image]

Both are freeware.

Answer (score 1):

[**Notebook BatteryInfo 1.2.0.20**](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/Notebook-BatteryInfo.html) is about as accurate as it gets with 'dumb laptop batteries'

[image]

(Doesn't require the **.NET** Framework)