# laptop battery charge

Tags: windows, windows-vista, software-rec, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows battery meter utility suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/36546/windows-battery-meter-utility-suggestions)

free software for laptop battery charge indicator for vista ?

Comment: What don't you like with the built in one?

Comment: i don't know its have built in ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/36546/windows-battery-meter-utility-suggestions

Comment: I've added an illustration of the built in one below, as an answer.

Comment: finally i like battery bar :-)

Comment: its duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/36546/windows-battery-meter-utility-suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vista has this one built-in, which shows in the notification area of the task bar:

[image]

I appear to be fully charged - it will show a power cord on it if you're running on mains power, and show different levels within the icon as the battery discharges.

Answer (score 1):

Vista has it built in, however I use (and like) [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/download.html)

Comment: I dont like this , any other tool like IBM

Comment: Well, what is the one IBM have and what don't you like / what do you want to see?

Comment: The one that comes with the ThinkVantage crap on ThinkPads puts a large, ugly progress-bar-style battery indicator in your taskbar so I suspect s?he wants something like that.

Comment: Someone wants to uglify their machine? Those taskbars are usually the first thing I remove... oh well!

Comment: its has some graphical display of battery in task bar